# Android AdModAds NullpointerException

Tags: android, ads

I added a `AdModAdsView` to my app. It seems to work.... however, in the Logcat I have the following error:

```
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498): An error occurred while destroying an AdWebView:
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(WebView.java:4361)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at     com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.destroy(SourceFile:252)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at com.google.ads.internal.c$e.run(SourceFile:191)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-02 18:55:41.170: E/Ads(17498):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) guideline.

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/banner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a150183ee58a0ed"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I don't have Java code...only XML.

Comment: Please clarify: How can you not have a Java code and still get Exceptions in LogCat?

Comment: I mean that the Ads staff is only in XML, i didn't code it in java. If you look in the logCat, you see that the null pointer exception is in the android package, not i my classes

Comment: I didn't solve it. Need your help.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling the package that gives you the error?

Comment: WHat do you mean with reinstalling?

Comment: The error occurs at android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient so did you try replacing the package with the most recent one or reinstalling ADT?

Comment: Currently i have the most recent one. I could try to replace it with an older version...

Comment: I hate to say this, but "Me too"

Comment: since today i didn't solve the problem...however, it doesn't affect the functionality of the application, so i could ignore the exception.

Comment: it does effect my application, crashes. Nexus 4

Comment: Well, i don't think your crash is caused by this nullpointer, since it is thrown in a secondary thread. Check it again, and maybe post your stacktrace.